# Get value from XML Node from XML Data source in SSRS Report if another node value exists

Tags: xml, reporting-services, datasource, reportbuilder, rdl

I have a Report (.rdl) file that uses an XML data source.  One of the XML nodes is 'Tax' that I need to display on the report.  However, if another value exists in the XML dataset, I need to use get and display a different node's value for the Tax.  Here is a minimized version of the XML datasource.

```
<Query>
 <XmlData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
   <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustomerName>Customer Name</CustomerName>
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <CustomerId>12345</CustomerId>
      <Tax>0.56</Tax>
      <parts>
        <part>
          <Category>Category1</Category>
          <Items>
            <Item>
              <ItemDescription>OtherItem1</ItemDescription>
              <ItemTotal>0.79</ItemTotal>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <ItemDescription>NewSalesTax</ItemDescription>
              <ItemTotal>0.99</ItemTotal>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <ItemDescription>OtherItem2</ItemDescription>
              <ItemTotal>0.59</ItemTotal>
            </Item>
          </Items>
        </part>
      </parts>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</Customer>
```

In the above XML, If "NewSalesTax" value exists for the ItemDescription node, I need to display the corresponding value of the ItemTotal node for the Tax value.  (ie 0.99)

I can check if the node exists using the SUM function:

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!ItemDescription.Value="NewSalesTax",1,0))
```

But I am not sure how to target the corresponding ItemTotal value if it is found.  Also note that I cannot rely on the Item being in a certain position within the Items Group.  It can exist, not exist, be first, last or in the middle of the group.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with an XML datasource, but if the Item Total works similarly to the Item Description field, the expression would be something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ItemDescription.Value = "NewSalesTax", Fields!ItemTtotal.Value, CDEC(0)))
```

Which reads as the SUM of the Item Total if the Description is New Sales Tax. The CDEC is used to convert the zero to a decimal to match the source type.